# Batch File Syntax to get files from FTP server

Tags: html-lists

I wanna ask you for a question. I have trouble to get all files from FTP Server. usually, I get all file using command line/terminal with syntax, eq : get a.txt (very very wasting my time with login authentication first)

So, my expectation is I wanna get all file from FTP server, with a script(batch), So I'm not wasting my time using terminal/command line. I just run it. Of course, login authentication included in the script.  Would you help me please ?

Thanks

Regards

Frans

Answer (score 1):

Here's a DOS/Windows .bat file:

```
FTP -v -i -s:ftpscript.txt
```

Here's the contents of "ftpscript.txt:

```
open myftpserver.com
myusername
mypassword
lcd c:\MyDirectory
binary
get MyFile.bin
disconnect
bye
```